# Mostrar alertas em um Console Application c#

Tags: c#, console, alert

Já aviso que talvez minha duvida seja muito primária, mas vamos lá...
Estou fazendo um projeto do tipo console em c#, mas estou com problemas para exibir alertas de erros. O que eu queria fazer era deixar uma parte do console separada para alertas, e quando o usuário fizer alguma coisa errada, mostrar essa região, caso contrario, ela permanece oculta.
Alguém já fez algo parecido ou pode dar dicas de como mostrar alertas de erros. Aceito outras Soluções e dicas.
Desde já, grato à todos.

Comment: pode ser em uma mensageBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom estou a deduzir que esteja usando o Windows:
Você pode colocar a mensagem de erro em uma messgeBox:

usando o

> System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

        public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr h, string m, string c, int type);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MessageBox de erro");
            Console.ReadLine();
            MessageBox((IntPtr)0, "Erro", "Error", 0);
        }
    }
}
```

ou usando o

> System.Windows.Forms não esqueça de adicionar a referencia em seu
>   projeto:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MessageBox de erro");
            Console.ReadLine();
            MessageBox.Show("Erro", "Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, me atendeu perfeitamente. Muitíssimo obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @RicardoAlves Tenta formular melhor suas próximas, para não ficar em pendente  segue um link para te ajudar - pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask